# How to execute javascript inside a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, pdo

I have a php page that confirms email account for verification.

I want to do is when the page redirect i want to clear all localstorage and trigger my click event in my javascript.

My problem is my script inside my php file doesnt execute.

my entire php code in my verify.php

```
<?php

include_once('database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $vemail = $_GET['vemail'];
    $vhash = $_GET['vhash'];

    $search = "SELECT user_email, user_hash, user_active FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email = :vemail AND user_hash = :vhash AND user_active = '0'";

    $verify = $db->prepare($search);
    $verify->bindParam(':vemail', $vemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $verify->bindParam(':vhash', $vhash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $verify->execute();
    $match = $verify->rowCount(); 

    if($match > 0){         

        $qup = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_active='1' WHERE user_email= :vemail AND user_hash = :vhash AND user_active='0'";

        $query = $db->prepare($qup);
        $query->bindParam(':vemail', $vemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':vhash', $vhash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();  

        header('Location: http://pro13.pnp.gov.ph/nup-application'); 

    ?>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            localStorage.clear();   
            $(".show-page[data-page=Email_verified]").trigger("click"); 
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        exit;
    }else{

        header('Location: http://pro13.pnp.gov.ph/nup-application'); 

        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            localStorage.clear();   
            $(".show-page[data-page=Email_alreadyVerified]").trigger("click");  
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please accept an answer or add your own answer and accept it. Doing that will prevent appearing this question as unanswered. @user3986930

Answer (score 3):

Of course it doesn't get executed because you're telling the browser to redirect to a different page. The browser doesn't care about anything else anymore.

Solution: Use javascript redirection instead of redirection via header response.

Example: Instead of this

```
header('Location: http://pro13.pnp.gov.ph/nup-application'); 

?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        localStorage.clear();   
        $(".show-page[data-page=Email_verified]").trigger("click"); 
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    exit;
```

do this

```
?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        localStorage.clear();   
        $(".show-page[data-page=Email_verified]").trigger("click"); 
        window.location.href = 'http://pro13.pnp.gov.ph/nup-application';
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    exit;
```

Comment: Note, though...if the response doesn't include that element, the script isn't going to work anyway.  The previous page is gone, replaced by the one you're generating now. You can't tell the browser to click stuff on it.

Comment: @cHao I don't know how his page looks like or how it's build, so I can't really tell if there is still this element (because it was printed before parsing verify.php) or if it's gone. So I just included it. If the element is gone, of course he has to remove that. But without knowing if the form is really going straight to verify.php or first to a different script, I can't really help in that case.

Comment: Yeah...there's not enough info to know whether that element is there or not. Nothing wrong with your answer.  :)  The OP seems a bit confused about what runs when, though, so i thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand server-side and client-side. PHP is a server-side script which is executed on your web server doing database quering, page rendering and responding to your browser's requests.

Once the PHP server sends its response to your browser, you get (usually) a HTML page that is parsed by your web browser. This is the client side. Javascript runs on the client side, meaning that it can play only with what's already on the page (with AJAX exceptions, of course).

I don't see in your PHP script the part that renders the form in which I believe is located the email field.